# F# WPF MouseMove params

Tags: wpf, user-interface, f#, msdn

```
canvas.MouseMove.Add(move canvas update)

MouseMove.Add( p1 p2 p3)
```

Usually I see this use and documentation, two params --
(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
-- which I take to be move and canvas in this example code, taken from F#.NET Journal's
Computational geometry: quick hull.

Is update some delagate? or routing bubble info to MouseMove.Add?

I'm just not gettng it. Any help welcome. Thanks. Art

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer from kvb gives all the theory, so I thought I could also add a code sample. I don't know the source of the snippet, so I'll make some guesses based on the names - hopefully it will be useful even if it may not be completely same as the original sample.

As kvb says, the code `move canvas update` is actually a function call that *returns* a function, which is then added as a handler to the `MouseMove` event.

This means that `move` could be declared as follows:

```
let move (canvas:Canvas) (update:unit -> unit) (me:MouseEventArgs) =
  // This function gets called when the mouse moves
  // - values me.X and me.Y give the current mouse location
  // - we can access 'canvas' that was declared when registering handler
  // - we can call 'update' to do some more work...
  // Pseudo-example:
  canvas.Children.[0].Width <- me.X
  update()
```

When registering the event handler, the code `move canvas update` specifies the first two arguments of the `move` function, so that the handler can access `canvas` value that was probably declared in the place where the handler is registered (without the use of mutable variables!)

```
let canvas = new Canvas() // Create canvas
let update () = ... // some function that performs update

// Register handler and give it canvas and update as first two arguments
canvas.MouseMove.Add(move canvas update)
```

This should also explain why the event handler does not need to take `sender:object` as the first argument - you can pass the `canvas` (which is the sender) as a first argument using *partial function application* in a statically typed way (so you don't have to cast `object` to `Canvas`).

Comment: Really guys a BIG F# FUN F#UN THANK YOU!!  (without the use of mutable variables!) I'm working through the details, to make sure I really get it, but I thank you for pointing me in the correct direction. I was on the C# thinking side of the C# F# GUI interface. I need to think FUNCTIONAL! Trying.  val move : IInputElement -> (int -> unit) -> Input.MouseEventArgs -> unit

Answer (score 4):

Unless you've got a typo, `move canvas update` is the application of the function `move` to the values `canvas` and `update`, none of which you are showing; this is not a set of 3 separate arguments being passed.

In general, in F# events work slightly differently than they do in other .NET languages.  When you use the `Add` method, you pass a function which takes a single `EventArgs` subclass, not the sender and the event args.  If you want to access the sender from within the handler, then use `AddHandler` instead; usually this isn't necessary because the sender is just the object on which you're adding the handler, so you don't need to get a separate reference to it from within the handler.

Comment: I would guess that `move` takes three parameters, the third being a `MouseEventArgs`. In that case, this is just partially-applying the first two parameters to the function, in order to get the function signature expected by `Add` - a function that has a single `MouseEventArgs` parameter.

Comment: @Joel - yes, that seems likely.  However, it's hard to explain exactly what the example does without knowing how `move` and `update` are defined.